# how to install model_evaluation_utils

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to model evaluate the performance of our deep learning models. And below is my code. However, I still get

> No module named 'model_evaluation_utils'

Is there any pip installation or conda that could solve this problem?

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array, array_to_img
from keras.models import load_model
import model_evaluation_utils as meu # throws error
```

Comment: Maybe rewind a little. What guide or other documentation suggested to `import model_evaluation_utils` in the first place?

Comment: this is where the answer is for your problem as you will see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69568847/11157710

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not a publicly available library, there must be a model_evaluation_utils.py file which is imported in the code and is used.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of "model_evaluation_utils" can be found in the following github repository:

[link](https://github.com/dipanjanS/hands-on-transfer-learning-with-python/blob/master/notebooks/Ch06%20-%20Image%20Recognition%20and%20Classification/model_evaluation_utils.py)